# Facebook Like or Like Box not showing in my web page

Tags: facebook

I've read through the various threads here regarding problems with the Facebook Like widgets, however I still cannot get mine to show in any browser.

I've ran my site through the debugger tool that Facebook has, and I only got a warning regarding an og:locale property, which I don't think is causing the issue.

See the simple html below, can anyone help here?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/myGFC/" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande">Text here</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>New Web Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F

%2Flyndonreid.com

%2Fcontact&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action   
=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"    
allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; 
height:px"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but what exactly is this plugin? Is it an older method?

Comment: This is the older way of adding a like button as now it has changed to XFBML and HTML5 code where you can go to this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/  as the code you mentioned is with XFMBL

Comment: Thanks, is XFBML dependent on HTML5? I didn't see that in any of the documentation. Ideally, I'd like to get he Like Box working but this may work with the http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall plugin to achieve the same thing

Comment: This could be used if you send XFBML from your server via ajax and want to render it client side. XFBML enables you to incorporate FBML into your websites and IFrame applications.And ofcourse you can use the neosmart as internally they too use the same.