# Facebook "Like" button not always shown

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-authentication

I implemented a like button for my website via iframe, but it only shows when people are logged into Facebook, is that normal?

Comment: I wish. Getting those damn things all the time is really annoying when you don't use facebook.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779881/facebook-like-or-like-box-not-showing-in-my-web-page help in any way?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. It has to do with the "Show this count only to users in the following countries" - or something similar. Turn that off and it will always show the count.

Go to your Facebook page, click on Edit Page > Manage Permissions > Country Restrictions. Make sure nothing is in this box.

I had to dig deep to find this solution for me a few months ago but it's worked like a charm ever since.

Comment: Anytime, if it works, make sure to click on the check mark next to my answer!